# How do i create a backward triangle in java using for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I need to make a triangle that looks like this

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
```

Currently i have a working one that looks like

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

using the loop :

```
public static void standard(int n)
   {
      for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
      {
         for(int c = 1; c <= x; c++)
         {
            System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

How do i go about making this work

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
```

Here is my attempt:

```
public static void backward(int n) 
{ 
    for(int x = 7; x <= n; x++) 
    { 
        for(int y = 1; y >= x; y--) 
        {
            if (x >= y) 
            { 
                System.out.print("*");
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.print("");
            }
         }
         System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add padding to your output decrease padding by one each line...by padding I mean space.

Comment: Think about printing spaces as well as asterisks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On every line print `n` chars: if index `c < n - x`, print space, otherwise print asterisk:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) 
        System.out.print(c < n - x ? ' ' : '*');    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output (n = 6):

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
******
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void standard(int n)
   {
      for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
      {
```

**New Code Here**

```
         for (int b = 0; b <= (n - x); b++)
            System.out.print(" ");
```

**This code adds spaces before adding stars. since a triangle is rect over 2, we know that total length will be n each time, and we are just making the others spaces to only show triangle**

```
         for(int c = 1; c <= x; c++)
         {
            System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void triangle(int n) {

        // create first line
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(2 * n + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            out.append(' ');
        }
        out.append('*');

        // repeatedly remove a space and add a star
        while (n-- > 0) {
            System.out.println(out);
            out.deleteCharAt(0);
            out.append("*");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the loop so that `x` denotes the number of spaces and print that number of spaces first and then print the the chars missing to fill the line:

```
for (int x = n-1; x >= 0; x--) {
    for (int c = 0; c < x; c++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int c = x; c < n; c++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```